# how to send FCM message to certain Platform and last app engagement?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

in Firebase console I can send FCM message based on the App Platform and last app engagement like this

[image]

currently I am using Node JS Cloud function and Firebase Admin SDK, and I want to send FCM message programmatically based on the platform (android or iOS) and last app engagement like in the console above.

how to do that programmatically? I have tried to find the documentation, but I can't find it :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to send them to specific platforms. For example:

```js
const topicName = 'industry-tech';

const message = {
  notification: {
    title: 'Sparky says hello!'
  },
  android: {
    notification: {
      imageUrl: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
  apns: {
    payload: {
      aps: {
        'mutable-content': 1
      }
    },
    fcm_options: {
      image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
  webpush: {
    headers: {
      image: 'https://foo.bar.pizza-monster.png'
    }
  },
  topic: topicName,
};

admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

You can check more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms).